# Edit webcam video settings

Tags: drivers, software-recommendation, webcam

So I have a pretty cheap webcam and while it is 1080p, the colors and saturation all are not that great. Is there some software that can help me edit the settings for the webcam which will persist gloabally in applications like Zoom and Discord?

I am running Ubuntu 20.10.

UPDATE:

I found two tools in [this](https://www.techytalk.info/webcam-settings-control-ubuntu-linux/) article. The two tools are called **Gtk-v4l** and **Guvcview** but they both do not work for me.